# Vaadin's vaadinBoootstrap.js

Tags: tomcat, vaadin

I meet confusing issue!

I'm using Vaadin(7) framework to create some (quiet simple) app. When I'm testing it in Eclipse, everything works fine. But when i deploy my project into Tomcat, some mysteries starts...

When I "run" the application from Manager App, there is just the message:

> Failed to load the bootstrap javascript: ./VAADIN/vaadinBootstrap.js

But when I type the same address to the browser (Firefox) manually, it works fine again.

I've done a little investigation about that and I found that there are a few people with the same issue but no satisfying solution.

Only thing I found out is that when I use Manager App there is some Cookie, which isn't there when I call it directly.

```
 Cache-Control  no-cache
 Content-Length 1929
 Content-Type   text/html
 Date   Wed, 02 Apr 2014 07:13:40 GMT
 Expires    Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT
 Pragma no-cache
 Server Apache-Coyote/1.1
 Set-Cookie JSESSIONID=F773E7AEDDDE7087CBF46C778CF5353A; Path=/SystematicTool-1.0.1/;  HttpOnly
```

vs.

```
Cache-Control   no-cache
Content-Length  1929
Content-Type    text/html
Date    Wed, 02 Apr 2014 06:42:28 GMT
Expires Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT
Pragma  no-cache
Server  Apache-Coyote/1.1
```

Could you please give me a clue how to repair this strange behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to explicitly enable cookie tracking in your `web.xml`:

```
<session-config>
    <tracking-mode>COOKIE</tracking-mode>
</session-config>
```

Comment: What is the reasoning behind this? Why did the change of tracking mode help?

Comment: Issue is quite old and I have no recollection why this was the solution. Sorry :(

Answer (score 1):

The following [hint from the Vaadin Framework Forum](https://vaadin.com/forum#!/thread/2438273/2442338) helped me:

> In your deployment descriptor (web.xml), do you have the VaadinServlet mapped to some other path than "/*"? If you do, you must provide mapping for /VAADIN/* path as well.
>
> Please see section 4.8.3 from here Book of Vaadin (https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/application.environment.html) [...].

Though in the meantime it is:

```
@WebServlet(value = "/*", asyncSupported = true)
@VaadinServletConfiguration(productionMode = false, ui = MyProjectUI.class)
public class MyProjectServlet extends VaadinServlet {
}
```