# Faild to load vaadinBootstrap.js with Spring + WebServlet 3.0

Tags: java, spring, twitter-bootstrap, tomcat7, vaadin7

I am working with Vaadin 7.7 and SpringFramework with Maven.

The code I made worked last time, but today it does not work.
The error message is `Failed to load bootstrap javascript : ./VAADIN/vaadinBootstrap.js?v=7.7.0`.

I have searched the internet, and found this.
[Vaadin's vaadinBoootstrap.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22804412/vaadins-vaadinboootstrap-js)

I says I need `session-config` in `web.xml`. However, I do not have `web.xml` since I am using servlet version `3.X`. So I add this statement to my `WebApplicationInitializer`. My code is below.

```
public class FarmInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {
    static private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Logger.class);

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext arg0) throws ServletException {
        System.out.println("=== Starts ===");
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        ctx.register(ServletConfig.class);
        ctx.register(FileConfig.class);
        ctx.register(DBConfig.class);


        //Solution of vaadinBootstrap.js?
        Set<SessionTrackingMode> sessionConfigSet = new HashSet<>();
        sessionConfigSet.add(SessionTrackingMode.COOKIE);
        arg0.setSessionTrackingModes(sessionConfigSet);

        arg0.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(ctx));
        registerServlet(arg0);
        System.out.println("=== Ends ===");
    }

    private void registerServlet(ServletContext ctx){
        Dynamic dispatcher = ctx.addServlet("vaadin", SpringVaadinServlet.class);
        dispatcher.addMapping("/");
        dispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(0);
        logger.info("=== DONE ===");
    }
}
```

But It does not work still. Is there any solution for this problem?
My server is `Tomcat 7.X`. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you tried to map your vaadin servlet as /* (instead of /) or to add a mapping for /VAADIN/*

```
dispatcher.addMapping("/*");
```